# How to fix Google Authentication DB access issue in Odoo v13

Tags: google-authentication, odoo-13

I have configured the Google Authentication from 'General Settings->Integrations' and provided the Client ID and got the 'Login with Google' button in Login page.

When I provide the gmail details, it creates an user in database and redirects back to login screen with an error like - 'Only employee can access this database. Please contact the administrator.'

How it can be fixed? I'm trying to implement that, any user can login to Odoo through Gmail credentials. Please guide me.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the portal module.

Comment: @DipenShah Yes it's installed, still the same.